# How to deploy a nodejs web application on an enterprise level

Tags: node.js, web-applications, network-programming, web-deployment, local-network

I'm developping a nodejs web application and I want to know how to deploy the app on enterprise level not on the cloud (Heroku and similar). 
Please keep the explanation as simple as possible as I'm not an expert. I think that the answer to this problem should include something about having a local enterprise network but I don't know the details.

The end result should be that any user inside the enterprise could for example open the browser at some specific link and use the application.

Comment: Could you provide more details on why you are cloud averse?

Comment: You will need a server. But "entreprise level" seems a bit broad in terms of size, security requirement, infrastructure, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You literally just need a computer connected to the enterprise network and your application running there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be great if you have some references or examples that explain the process from connecting the computer to the enterprise network to deployment of the application for nodejs based applications?